# Form disappears on function call

Tags: javascript, forms

I have the following button inside a form and a javascript method `SizeGuide`

```js
var four="4OZ"
function SizeGuide(){
  if(document.getElementById("training").checked)
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = four;
}
```

```html
 <button id="hello" onclick="SizeGuide()">Size:</button><p id="show"></p>
```

When clicking on the button, I just want to display the variable. My problem is that the variable is showing for a second or so then it crashes and the form disappears. "training" is a simple input radio button. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your button is submitting the form. Instead of inline code, use `hello.addEventListener("click", SizeGuide);`. Then add an `e` parameter: `function SizeGuide(e)` to be able to access the click event. Inside the function, call `e.preventDefault();` to avoid the form submission.

Comment: Hello, I added the e.preventDefault() call inside the function but I'm not quite sure what you mean with instead of inline code, where should I add the event listener?

Comment: Just use the line as-is in your script, outside any function. Just make sure the script is below the form, so the button already exists when the script runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't declared a type for the button, it defaults to a submit button. Add a `type="button"` attribute and it will no longer submit the form.

```
<button type="button" id="hello" onclick="SizeGuide()">Size:</button><p id="show"></p>
        ^^^^ set the type
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your checked method does but you have to stop the default form action by calling `preventDefault()`

```js
var four="4OZ"
function SizeGuide(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form action

  if(document.getElementById("training").checked){
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = four;
  }
}
```

```html
 <button id="hello" onclick="SizeGuide(event)">Size:</button><p id="show"></p>
```

Comment: The checked method checks if the radio button is checked :) Thank you for your solution, it worked but MrCode's solution is easier to implement, no need for additional js. I Will definitely keep in mind the preventDefault so thank you again!